# Match <p> tags that contains 1 or more <strike> tags

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to match any p tag that has one or more strike tags inside it. 
For example:

```
<p><strike>Match this</strike></p>
<p style="">Hey! <strike>Match this</strike> also</p>
<p><strike>Match this</strike> entire <strike>p tag</strike></p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried <p[negative lookahead for anything except </p>]<strike>(.*?)</p> but i can`t get it to work maybe my syntax is wrong or something

Comment: which language are you using...

Comment: `<p>((?!</p>).)*<strike>.*?</p>`, but I'm surprised no one has warned you about parsing html the cthulu way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Oh, sorry.  `<p[^>]*>((?!</p>).)*<strike>.*?</p>`.  See that thing in action: http://regexr.com?33hr7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
<p[^<>]*>.*?<strike>.*?</p>
```

But parsing an html with regex is not recommended method.

Instead use an html parser like [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)..

---

You can use this code to retrieve it using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

//strikeNodes contains all the p nodes
var strikeNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[strike]");
//pText contains all p nodes in textual format
List<string> pText= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[strike]").Select(x=>x.OuterHtml);
```